# ActiveRecord ignores validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

Heya im pulling my hair out right now

```
class Referal < ApplicationRecord
  validates :pax, :presence => true
  validates :customer_email, presence: true

  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  self.implicit_order_column = "created_at"

  belongs_to :referer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :customer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :business
```

```
<Referal:0x000055f8a468b058
 id: nil,
 state: nil,
 handle: nil,
 sec_code: nil,
 pax: nil,
 booking_date_time: nil,
 business_id: "224cd62b-3d29-41ca-a1be-f308815514b2",
 customer_id: nil,
 referer_id: "cdfb1861-d5e4-4650-9783-4189cffde6bd",
 customer_email: nil,
 customer_mobile: nil,
 customer_last_name: nil,
 customer_first_name: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

```
x.valid?                                                                                                                                                                          
=> true
```

i tried multiple ways but it seems since i have multiple FK's in the model it only validates the ft for Business and Referer

how do i enforce the validator for additional fields? thanks

Comment: You can have any number of validations. Something else is going on. Please show your code for creating the referal and calling x.valid?.

Comment: i was just creating it in the console and that seems to ignore validations .. in running code it was working fine - ISSUE was between keyboard and computer - closed

Comment: It could also be that the validations were added after the console was loaded, if you run `reload!` or exit and restart the console, does that help?